# Streaming Data from Azure Blobs Back to Client

Tags: c#, azure, stream, blob, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.Net Web API, I am developing a service which (amongst other things) retrieves data from Azure, and returns it to the client.

One way of doing this would be to read the netire blob into a buffer, and then write that buffer to the response. However, I'd rather stream the contents, for better performance.

This is simple with the Azure API:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(buffer);
}
```

And elsewhere in the code, this is returned to the client:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(buffer);
```

But can I be certain that the MemoryStream won't be closed/disposed before the client finishes reading?

Comment: One alternative to consider is direct-downloading content from blob to browser, and bypassing your VM's altogether (reducing VM load). I posted an answer about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30468172/272109).

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't wrap your memory stream in a "using" statement you will be fine. If you do use "using" you end up with a weird race condition where it works sometimes and fails at other times.
I have code like yours in production and it works fine.

Only thing to be mindful of is that the whole blob is copied into memory before anything is sent to the client. This may cause memory pressures on your server and initial lag, depending on the size of the file.
If that is a concern, you have a couple of options. 
One is to create a "lease" on the blob and give the user a URL to read it direct from blob storage for a limited time. That only works for low security scenarios though.

Alternatively you can use chunked transfer encoding. Basically, you read the file from blob storage in chunks and sends it to the client in those chunks. That saves memory - but I have not been able to make it work async, so you are trading memory for threads. Which is the right solution for you will depend in your specific circumstances.

(I have not got the code to hand, post a comment if you want it and I'll try to dig it out, even if it's a bit old).