# How to work with file delivery to the client in asp.net mvc without downloading the files on the web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to avoid having to download files of **azure storage blob** on the web server before delivering it to the client, is there any way for the asp.net mvc to make the browser understand that it is receiving a file url and have it open as if I had returned a file, for example : A FileResult?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467013/how-to-download-a-file-to-browser-from-azure-blob-storage?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: How to generate a url with token is not the real problem here, I'm already doing this, however, I want to return this url to the user and make your browser understand that it is receiving a file to open the save dialog box. With asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the proper way, but the following code served me:

```
    public RedirectResult Test()
    {
        ...

        return new RedirectResult(uri.ToString());
    }
```