# Returning File() returns more bytes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Consider the following code:

```
//get bytes
var query = await _storage.Get(attachment.Id, General.ContainerType.Uploads);
//just for the sake of debugging
var mem = new MemoryStream(query);
//return the uploaded file
return File(mem, MimeTypesMap.GetMimeType(attachment.FileName), attachment.FileName);
```

After uploading a .jpg image of 67kb and then downloading it with this method, the returned image is 107 kb. I have checked whether the bytes are stored and retrieved correctly and they indeed are constistent with what I have uploaded.  If I upload a text file and return it the content and the size is correct.

I assume File() does some magic, but I can't figure out why and what?

Comment: File shouldn't be adding anything interesting. What do the response headers look like?

Comment: {"date":["Thu"," 21 Sep 2017 14:39:27 GMT"],"server":["Kestrel"],"x-powered-by":["ASP.NET"],"transfer-encoding":["chunked"],"content-type":["application/octet-stream"],"access-control-allow-origin":["*"],"x-sourcefiles":["=?UTF-8?B?QzpcZ2l0aHViXHVuaWt5dGVcc3JjXFVuaWt5dGUuU1BBXGFwaVxmaWxldXBsb2FkXGFmYzM5MTg1LWQ2MTMtNGJlYy1jYTY1LTA4ZDRmZjk3NzdiYQ==?="],"content-disposition":["attachment; filename=l.jpg; filename*=UTF-8''l.jpg"],"connection":["close"]} @Tratcher

Comment: What is `_storage` and what do you get from `mem.Length` in this example?

Comment: @KirkLarkin storage is an azure cloud storage and mem.Length - The stream builds its length from the length of the byte array

Comment: @Hristo i believe this has more to do with the way you're storing the uploaded file. i believe some manipulation is happening at that level.

Comment: @Hristo check uploaded file via [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) or similar - what size is it?

Comment: @Dmitry the file was correctly uploaded, it was something related to the transfer between client and server. anyway files shouldn't be sent by the web server-he should only serve urls to the files:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by providing a URL to the azure blob storage file and adding permissions for a few minutes : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468172/4487530

Answer (score 0):

Its not about the `File` but it is something to do with the `MemoryStream` , 
for getting bytes stored in memorystream passing an entire stream is not appropriate way better to use its convenient `ToArray()` method. You could try with the [Binarywriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried both solutions..nothing seems to change in the output