# Files stored under Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my application hosted in Azure App Service, we upload some images which are stored directly to Azure blob.

After sometime we can view images from application but anyhow user fetch blob URL so he/she can simply check images without application.

Is there any way like we can view images from my application only not from direct URL.

I tried keeping it private then was not visible to user from myapplication.

Is there some way so we can store these images securely so authentic users from my application can access or view?

Comment: Blobs already store your content securely. Have you considered using a Shared Access Signature to provide direct access? (if it's a private blob, that's pretty much the only way to direct-access without having a storage account's credentials) - Or stream your content through your web app?

Comment: FYI I answered an almost-identical question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468172/272109).

Comment: flagged as dupe, and its generally a question asking for the code to work with Azure blob

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to restrict Azure Storage API's to only allow your application to access content and not user if user happens to get the blob link. I don't think adding CDN into the mix would change that either since content from CDN can also be [accessed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn#step-2-enable-cdn-for-the-storage-account) via an endpoint.

If you have a two tier architecture with Web portal and Web api, then your web API can fetch the content from Azure Storage upon user request and then stream the content as `http response message` to your web portal. User this way can only see final content as image without knowing where image came from.

But this can make your application slow because of an extra hop to get content from web api. The whole point of web portal having the link to blob is to get it faster.

Regarding security, if the blobs are open to read then anyone can read them. If you want to restrict to certain users then you have to come up with logic in your web app to issues `SAS tokens` to users for a limited time.