# Create shareable URI from azure blob storage with SAS (NODEJS)

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, download

I am trying to create a URI with a Shared Access Signature for a single file in an azure blob storage. I want to create this on my backend and send the link to my angular frontend so that the user can directly download the file.

I have found a similar example for C# here: [How to download a file to browser from Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467013/how-to-download-a-file-to-browser-from-azure-blob-storage/30468172#30468172)

However I´m having trouble finding the correct way for NodeJS. I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas however I´m not sure how to use that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to get blob sas url.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService('storage connection');
// Create a SAS token that expires in an hour
    // Set start time to five minutes ago to avoid clock skew.
    var startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 5);
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 60);

    permissions = azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ;

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: permissions,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };
    var container='test';
    var blobName='test.txt';
    var sasToken = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);
    var url=blobService.getUrl(container,blobName,sasToken);
    console.log(url);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I managed to create an URL with the supplied example. However the url does not contain the parameters 'se' and 'st' and thus I get the error "<AuthenticationErrorDetail>se is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail>" when using the created URL. I´ve used the same code to create the dates and the sharedAccessPolicy.

Comment: Please share your code, because check my picture, there is 'se' and 'st'.

Comment: I´ve found the issue, I had a typo in "AccessPolicy" :) . Thank you very much!