# How to pass an Azure Blob in memory through Flask in Python

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I'm a novice at both python and programming in general. I've gotten pretty far with my Terraform Private Registry API here.

I have the situation where I am pulling a zip from Azure Blob storage, the code is hosted in a managed identity azure web app and it has permissions to the blob.

What is essentially happening is I'm pulling it down and then passing it out via send_file.

However, I've had to write it to a temp directory, which persists.

So eventually, without a cleanup task, this will fill up with garbage files.

I tried to figure out how to do it all in memory, or to use the Temp files and context but it just won't work.  By the time it hits the send_file part, even if I put it inside the With, it's passing rubbish or says the file path doesn't exist.

It feels like this should be quite possible so am hoping someone can steer me or even just tell me. I've spent hours trying to figure out the iobytes style stream method and it's a bit beyond me so am hoping for a hand-up.

I'd even settle for a way for the directory to clean up automatically but from what I understand after the return part of the Flask function, you're done, and nothing after it triggers.

```py
@app.route('/v1/modules/<namespace>/<name>/<provider>/<version>/local.zip', methods=['GET'])
def downloadfile(namespace, name,provider,version):
    bloburl = f'{azblobstoragehost}/{azcontainer}/v1/modules/{namespace}/{name}/{provider}/{version}/local.zip'
    token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(bloburl, credential=token_credential)  
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    # create a temporary directory using the context manager
    #f = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir = "temp")
    f = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir = "temp") #this one works
    with open(f'{f}/local.zip', "wb") as my_blob:
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
    return send_file(f'{my_blob.name}')
```

Comment: There's no need to download a blob first; aside from streaming blob content, you can return a uri to a blob, which allows the content to stream directly from blob to client. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468172/272109) for more info. That answer isn't in python but should at least give you a perspective.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon I'll give that a try. I'm using Azure AD managed Identity, will it be able to use that method ?

Comment: You should be able to generate a Shared Access Signature that gives temporary access to a specific blob or container. There are docs on this, so I would suggest giving that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I got this working with some effort !
I’m slightly concerned about using a sas though in case it got snooped ?
Is there actually a way to pass the file like I said or is there nothing to fear and a sas can’t be snooped and used ?